# Powershell & SQL Jobs - Passing errors so job step will fail

Tags: sql-server, powershell, batch-file, error-handling

Good Day folks,

I hope someone can help me here.  I am a complete powershell n00b and I've been tasked with the following.

We have a SQL Server 2019 job which runs several stored procedures and then we have a step which calls a powershell command on a remove server.  The command we run currently is:

```
INVOKE-COMMAND -ComputerName remoteServer -ScriptBlock {D:\EXEs\application.bat 35 0 0 0 [PathDirectory] 0 A}
```

This batch file is simple.  It looks like:

```
@echo off
set CUR_YYYY=%date:~10,4%
set CUR_MM=%date:~4,2%
set CUR_DD=%date:~7,2%
set CUR_HH=%time:~0,2%
if %CUR_HH% lss 10 (set CUR_HH=0%time:~1,1%)

set CUR_NN=%time:~3,2%
set CUR_SS=%time:~6,2%
set CUR_MS=%time:~9,2%

set SUBFILENAME=%CUR_YYYY%%CUR_MM%%CUR_DD%-%CUR_HH%%CUR_NN%%CUR_SS%

D:\EXEs\InDesignPDFgen3\InDesignPDFgen.exe %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 > D:\EXEs\InDesignPDFgen3\Logs\output-%SUBFILENAME%.log 2> D:\EXEs\InDesignPDFgen3\Logs\error-%SUBFILENAME%.log
```

All this does is is run the actual application.  It also creates 2 text files on every run along with datestamps to the second.  One captures the Output when the process runs and the second is an error file.  I'm sure this could be done in powershell as well.

This is where we run into issues.  The first part of the application pulls data from SQL and then it runs indesign to create a bunch of PDFs. This application will crash at times.  Before we had the log files through the batch file in place, we could not tell where the process crashed to pinpoint what happened.  But now that we're using the batch file, if it crashes, it logs it via the batch file but our job step in SQL Server passes and allows other things to run with bad data.  We need the job to fail if there is a problem but randomly searching does not cover everything we're looking for and I can not seem to get a script to work.  I'm sure this all can be done via one powershell script.  I'm a SQL developer and to be honest, programming hurts my head.  Hoping someone has had a similar experience and can help me here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I all probability, `InDesignPDFgen` will set `errorlevel` non-zero, so you should be able to interpret the return errorlevel. Or, the logfile will be 0 bytes if there was no error, non-zero otherwise.

Comment: That's the issue.  The application hard crashes but it doesn't bubble up to the SQL Job step.  We've even tried creating a dummy batch file which sets the error level to something other than 0 and the SQL job still completes without issue :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Powershell will return a zero exit code unless you throw an error. Check `$LASTEXITCODE` after running the exe and throw if non-zero:

```
INVOKE-COMMAND -ComputerName remoteServer -ScriptBlock {D:\EXEs\application.bat 35 0 0 0 [PathDirectory] 0 A;if($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0) {throw "Non-zero exit code: $LASTEXITCODE"}}
```

Comment: Thank you Dan.  I'm still having issues using that command.  Even if the batch file does not have an issue, the SQL Agent seems to have issues running this. 

'INVOKE-COMMAND -ComputerName RemoteServer -ScriptBlock {D:\EXEs\InDesignPDFgen3\testFailure.bat;if($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0) {throw "Non-zero exit code: $LASTEXITCODE}}'

Unhandled Exception: System.FormatException: Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still new here as far as posting code.  It does not seem to want to allow me to enter code like above.

Comment: @Ron, are you saying you get a `FormattException` when you run a SQL Agent PowerShell job step with the command in my answer? If so, do you get the same error when run from a PowerShell prompt?

Comment: Thank you Dan.  I see what happened.  I left out the last double quote before the 2 curly braces.  It works in both systems.  Thank you!  

Ron  - I don't have enough of a reputation to upvote the answer, or I would.  Thanks again!

Comment: @Ron, you should be able to mark the answer even if you don't also upvote.